# Validate Json Object before casting it to POJO - using @requestBody

Tags: java, json, spring, validation

I would like to validate the incoming json object in controller before casting it to POJO using spring jackson.

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/createContact" , method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE , produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    public Contact createContact( @RequestBody Contact contact ) throws Exception
        {
            return ContactService.createContact( contact );
        }
```

My Contact.java

```
public class Contact
{

    private String ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    private String type = "contact";

    private String category;

    private String name;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that 'type' field should not be passed in the request json. I need to throw an exception if the consumer passes that value.

I can get the json as a Map or string and validate it and then cast it to POJO. But is it possible to validate it before direct casting?

Comment: Since the object is parsed using Jackson mapping, annotate your object accordingly, using Jackson XML annotations. That should solve your problem.

Comment: @Schaka - Annotating in the object level will be global. For certain requests i need to block the 'type' field in the request payload and throw exception but where as in other requests i need to accept 'type' field. Can u help me out with that?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with an interceptor which will extend [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html). For example, you can create a ContactRequestValidator class like below.

```
@Component("contactRequestInterceptor")
public class ContactRequestValidator implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o) throws Exception {
      // get the request payload using reader from httpServletRequest and do the validation 
      // and throw an exception if not valid and may handle it using an Spring MVC exception handler 
    }

    // other two methods omitted..
}
```

Then register the validator interceptor with

```
@Configuration
public class MVCConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("contactRequestInterceptor")
    private HandlerInterceptor contactRequestValidator;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(contactRequestValidator).addPathPatterns("/api/**"); // Also have the option to use Ant matchers
    }
}
```